# Converting Strings into the numeric unicode equivalent for each letter in the word using a loop using Java?

Tags: java, unicode

I've been trying to figure out how to convert `String`s into numeric Unicode that is from the user input. From the assignment, I know I'm suppose to use loops to transfer the words to Unicode but I'm uncertain how to do this.

I'm pretty sure it's suppose to be either a while or for loop. They said the while loop if for when you don't have a set iteration which I don't think this one does.

I have looked up Unicode and I'm still confused but I think this might be Unicode site: http://www.unicodetables.com/

Which lead me to the Basic Latin:
http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf

But I have no idea what to do with it.

I also saw another question that was similar to mine but used `ord()` but that was for Python so I don't know if Java has an equivalent.

The code that I have so far is here:
package calculate;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UniCal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String word1;
        String word2;

        String resultFullWord;
        int resultAbsVal = 0;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is your first word?");
        word1 = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("And your second word?");
        word2 = scanner.nextLine();

        resultFullWord = (word1 + " " + word2);
        System.out.println(resultFullWord);

        word = input("Enter a word: ")
                for letter in word:
                    print(letter + ': ', ord(letter)); 
    }

    // while (resultFullWord.equals(resultFullWord)) {
            // Do something ...
            // Get input into userChar
    // }

        // Math.abs
        System.out.println("Your absolute value based on your word is : " + resultAbsVal);
        scanner.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: The String in java are already build with unicode characters. You can simply use `toCharArray()` and work with the individual unicode characters. You can even cast them to `int` to get the "numeric unicode equivalent" of these characters.

Comment: Not quite, @Progman.  Java Strings are encoded in UTF-16.  That encodes BMP characters as their own code point values, but other Unicode characters are encoded as surrogate pairs.

Comment: @Progman  Thank you for the toCharArray(). I think that worked as the words from the strings made each letter on it's individual line. However I'm not sure how to cast them into int to get the numeric unicode equivalent? Do you have a link or an example?

Comment: @JackieTowns You can use `int i = (int)charValue;` to cast the character value to an integer value.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the key point that Java `char` values *already provide* a numeric encoding of Unicode, and also that Java `String`s have methods for extracting Unicode "code points" -- the numeric values that Unicode assigns to characters.

It's unclear exactly what the expectation of the assignment is.  If the "numeric unicode equivalent" means the UTF-16 code unit value, then you can just iterate over the `char`s of the string.  Depending on what method you use to print them, you may need to cast them to type `int` to get numeric results instead of numbers.

I suspect that the above is what the assignment expects you to do, since you seem to have had little or no introduction to Unicode concepts or terminology.  However, evantually you will need to be aware that UTF-16, and therefore Java Strings, encode the majority of Unicode characters as two-`char` "surrogate pairs".  If you're intended to print the numeric value of each *Unicode character* encoded by a `String`, as opposed to each Java `char`, then you need a different approach: you want to iterate over the *code points* represented by the `String`, not the `char`s.

To iterate over all the Unicode code points of a `String`, I would be inclined to use `String.codePoints()`, but that provides them to you in the form of an `IntStream`.  That's a really convenient form, except that it's not conducive to performing an explicit iteration via a `for` or `while` loop, and if you're new to Java then you may not have learned about streams yet.  In that case, you can use `String.codePointCount()` to find out how many code points the string contains, then use a `for` loop to iterate over the code point indexes, extracting each one via `String.codePointAt()`.

Comment: It is true that I've had bare basics of Java so far. I would like to try your String.codePointCount() and then using a for loop to iterate the code since that seems the most basic out of everything listed that I've learned so far. However, do you have any examples? I'm trying to get the code to work and so far I'm not even sure what I'm doing...

Comment: I sympathize, @JackieTowns, but any useful example I could provide would constitute most of a solution for the assignment.  You're meant to work it out for yourself -- that's how most of the learning happens.  It is in no one's interest to deny you that benefit.